# WPF - Bind window title to other project public settings

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml, data-binding

Apparently I like to complicate my life, but I feel it's worth it.

I have a Solution with more than one WPF projects (each builds into its own application: Server, Client etc.). I'd like to have some settings in one place (mostly labels, so when I change names I won't have to locate it throughout multiple files), so I created project "Common", in it Properties.settings, and in those some positions (ServerName, ClientName).

Now in Server.MainWindow I'd like to set Title property to Common.Properties.Default.ServerName. Of course in XAML. I unfortunately have no idea how to go about it.

Somewhere I found:

```
<ObjectDataProvider x:Key="odpsettings" ObjectType="{x:Type l:Properties.Settings}"></ObjectDataProvider>
```

but whatever I type I get

```
nested properties are not supported
```

Basically it doesn't work and I don't know where to start...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that doing something like `{x:Static common:Properties.Default.ServerName}` is not allowed, but having just `{x:Static common:Properties.Default}` is OK.

So all you need to do is set the binding source to `{x:Static common:Properties.Default}` and specify the requested key in the binding path, thus avoiding the whole unsupported nested types issue:

```
<Window Title="{Binding Source={x:Static common:Properties.Default}, Path=ServerName}">
```

Comment: Properties are auto-generated from designer, so in code I'd refer to it as: Common.Properties.Default.ServerName, so in XAML: Title="{x:Static common:Properties.Default.ServerName}" But I get: nested types are not supported

Comment: I could make those Properties a custom class with static properties, but maybe I don't have too?

Comment: It worked! Thank you very much. Now, for it to work I had to make a small change to xmlns: xmlns:common="clr-namespace:Common;assembly=Common"